# Duplicate Entries in SQLite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, cordova

I am fetching and storing phone numbers and contact names in a SQLite DB from an Android phone. Now my problem is that whenever I refresh/reload the app the SQL entries (phone and contacts) are inserted again and again giving rise to duplicate entries. How to stop this, I am using Phonegap, by the way!

I am using this simple code to populate the DB

```
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS details (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, phone TEXT)');
```

But it is causing double entries.

Comment: simple... delete all records before inserting... or do an availability check before inserting...  :)

Comment: But why are you storing the contacts if you reading them everytime on refresh or reload. Can u maintain a list of contacts?

Comment: How dumb I am, I could have saved the contacts in the DB, instead of retrieving them again and again... !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stopping this can be as easy as defining a two field primary key, like this :

```
CREATE TABLE contacts(
  name CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  address INTEGER,
  phone INTEGER NOT NULL,
  song VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (name, phone)
)
```

This key will ensure no entry in the database has the same name and phone.

Hope this helps !

Comment: He doesnt need to try initial insertion everytime.. This will be overhead as it will still be trying to insert all contacts on every refresh and restart of the app. But good query for avoiding further duplicates on every new entry inserted.

Comment: Only db knows if the record has been inserted before or not. There is no other way to check this. It has to be done at db level.

Comment: Short fyi: `INSERT INTO contacts (name, phone) values ('JustinT', NULL)`. Now repeat that a few times & you have several JustinT:s in your table. `NULL` isn't considered unique when compared with other `NULL` values.

Answer (score 0):

It will solve the duplicate entry problem:

```
sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO measure_table (measure) " + "VALUES ( '" + "Length" + "')");
```